# Maven settings file

Tags: maven, m2e

I have no settings file configured but m2e is still downloading dependencies :

Is there a default settings file that m2e uses if it cannot find the settings file in the .m2 folder ?

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Are you having issues of any sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Maven POM file inherits from the [super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM). That's where default Maven central repositories are defined. Have you ever wondered why Maven is always able to find public stuff even when you don't have remote repositories configured?

So.. if you don't have any settings.xml it doesn't matter, Maven will use the repositories defined in the super POM to find JARs, at least the public ones.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Maven will use the core maven respository found at http://mvnrepository.com/.

Most of the time this is usually satisfactory. You may find that in a more commercial context, businesses will have their own maven repository set up, which is where a custom maven settings file is used. There is also a settings file in your maven folder that maven will use.

Comment: I don't have settings file in my maven folder

Answer (score 0):

Maven installation comes with a configuration file for all users at **${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml**

You can still specify user level configuration at **${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml**